# Deleting millions of rows from PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

**Question in short**

How can I delete around 30M rows from a table with 3B rows without blowing up my PostgreSQL server?

**Question in detail**

I am using PostgreSQL database (AWS RDS, db.t4g.medium). I have one table to keep track of daily stocks of various items of my customers, with approximately the following rows:

- `supplier_id`: foreign key to customer table
- `retailer_id`: foreign key to customer table
- `ean`: varchar(13), not indexed
- `datetime`: indexed
- `quantity`: integer, not indexed

As of today, this table has 3 billion rows. Now I want to delete all rows for a given supplier. The naive approach would be to execute:

```
DELETE FROM stocks 
WHERE supplier_id = 200
```

This will result in a non-responsive database for at least 1 hour, after which I have killed the query (since it's making my entire webserver be non-responsive).

I then split up to delete them in batches, based per day. Since I am using Python+Django, it is easy to generate these SQL queries automatically.

```
DELETE FROM STOCKS 
WHERE supplier_id=200
AND datetime >= '2022-08-19T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz 
AND datetime < '2022-08-20T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz
```

This had solved the issue for the smaller suppliers (1M rows), but for a supplier with 30M rows, this still blows up. After 1 hour, it didn't finish deleting for a single day.

My question is: how can I make sure that this deletion occurs without consuming all resources of the database instance? Are there more clever ways to split it up? Are there other techniques available that I don't know about? I do not care too much about how long it takes (this is not a regularly recurring operation), as long as it is stable.

**Additional info**

This is the query plan for the deletion of all stocks for a supplier:

```
EXPLAIN
DELETE FROM stocks
WHERE supplier_id = 158;
```

```
Delete on stocks (cost=0.00..80052412.00 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Seq Scan on sa_inventory_stocktake  (cost=0.00..80052412.00 rows=36725650 width=6)
        Filter: (supplier_id = 158)
```

And this is the query plan for deleting the stocks of a supplier for a given day:

```
EXPLAIN
DELETE FROM stocks
WHERE supplier_id = 158
AND datetime >= '2022-08-19T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz 
AND datetime < '2022-08-20T00:00:00+00:00'::timestamptz;
```

```
Delete on stocks  (cost=92677221.21..92898902.60 rows=0 width=0)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on stocks  (cost=92677221.21..92898902.60 rows=56759 width=6)
        Recheck Cond: ((supplier_id = 158) AND (datetime >= '2022-08-19 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (datetime < '2022-08-20 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
        ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=92677221.21..92677221.21 rows=56759 width=0)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stocks_supplier_id_c50e0b94  (cost=0.00..892175.08 rows=36725650 width=0)
                    Index Cond: (supplier_id = 158)
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on stocks_lookup  (cost=0.00..91785017.50 rows=4614593 width=0)
                    Index Cond: ((datetime >= '2022-08-19 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (datetime < '2022-08-20 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))"
```

There are the following indices:

- BTREE on supplier_id, is_unique=False
- BTREE on retailer_id, is_unique=False
- BTREE on retailer_id,datetime, is_unique=False

Comment: Do you have indexes on these columns? And could you share the query plan?

Comment: t4g.medium for a table with 4B rows seems kind of nuts.  Could you upgrade that?  How many rows is one day for that one supplier?

Comment: @FrankHeikens: There are indices indeed, I have written them in the question. I don't know the query plan, running `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the delete query also already is too much to ask for. @jjanes: It's for around 3 years of data, so around 30k rows per day for this supplier, although it's not necessarily evenly distributed.

Comment: Use just explain, better just the plan than nothing

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: Doing in batches, including a range condition on the primary key, is one way to achieve that. Note that indexes on a single field where  conditions are on multiple fields are generally not useful (as indicated by the explain output showing Postgres ignoring them), and what is mentioned about indexes in the question does not address Frank’s comment - please show the index definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The below code is just an idea. In order not to lock too many rows at a time, we do this blockwise using PostgreSQL's row location `CTID`. Thus we delete the first n matches, then the next n, and so on, but by using the table's `CTID` we avoid reading disk blocks that we have already scanned before.

I am not a PostgreSQL developer. My code doesn't work. PostgreSQL's `RETURNING` clause does not allow aggregation. There may be even more errors in the code. But you get the idea, and I hope you or another PostgreSQL develeoper will be able to fix all issues and get this running.

```
create or replace procedure delete_from_big_table(p_supplier_id int)
$$
declare
  v_max_ctid tid = (0,0);
  v_count int;
begin
  loop
    with next_rows as 
    (
      select ctid 
      from big_table
      where supplier_id = p_supplier_id
      and ctid > v_max_ctid
      order by ctid
      fetch first 50000 rows only
    )
    delete from big_table
    where big_table.ctid in (select ctid from next_rows)
    returning max(ctid), count(*) into v_max_ctid, v_count;

    if v_count > 0 then
      commit;
    else
      exit;
    end if;
  end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

This will be slow, but who cares as long as all the other processes can run at about normal speed.